# how to solve the error that fs module is not found when used node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, fs

i want to use mongodb in my app that uses webpack and react,but it has 
a error:"Module not found:Error:can't resolve 'fs' in F:\nodeSpace\react\react-app\node_modules\mongo\lib\gridfs",then i try to  use the fs module in cmd system,and it works,and then i try to use the fs module in the app,it showes the error: "Module not found:Error:can't resolve 'fs' in F:\nodeSpace\react\react-app\app".

It's really appreciate you can help me to solve it.

Comment: You cannot use mongodb libraries "client side" in a browser based application. Instead you talk to an "intermediary" host based API which does the communicating to the database and talks to your browser over regular HTTP conversations. Not all nodejs libraries are "pure JavaScript" and thus cannot run in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Just add below lines in your webpack config file.

```
node: {
    fs: "empty" 
}
```

[For more reference](https://github.com/josephsavona/valuable/issues/9)

Comment: It's not just a matter of excluding the native code dependency, but rather that the attempt to use software in the browser that you simply cannot. MongoDB client libraries cannot be used in a browser based application. You instead connect to a server based process.

Comment: Am using  sitemap.js module which is not having any webpack.config fil. so how can I add the code?. I am new into react. When I try to install sitemap xml generating modules it is showing fs module is missing